# YouTube API v3 Order Parameter Possible Bug

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Looking at the [YouTube API v3 Search documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), it states that the order parameter is used to control ordering of API response resource results.  However, when attempting to order by date, I'm not receiving the results in reverse chronological order as specified. In fact, they are not in any order whatsoever.

API Request with order `date` using API Explorer UI:

[image]

Is there some other way I should be requesting for results to be ordered by the time they were published on YouTube? Is there a bug in the handling of the order API parameter?

Answer (score 0):

There's no bug; the 'order' parameter will sort results based on when the resources were created, This value may be slightly different than when a video is published, as a resource is created when an upload begins but a video is published when the upload finishes and is processed.

In this case, it looks like the 10 or so most recent videos were all uploaded at the exact same time (YouTube.com has a batch uploader), so you're getting the order they were created in, even though the published dates reflect minor differences (maybe a couple took a bit longer to upload or something). IF you scan the full list of results, though, you'll see they play out just fine in terms of their reverse chronological order.  And generally you probably won't have so many videos that were batch uploaded like this.

Comment: I see. So according to that information, the result set is in fact sorted, however by some other value than `publishedAt`.  Is it possible using the `fields` API request parameter to include tha attribute being sorted on in the result?  How does this correspond with the publishedBefore/publishedAfter API request parameters?  According to the documentation, "The publishedBefore/publishedAfter parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources **created** before/after the specified time".  So is the request arg evaluated against `publishedAt`, or the "createdAt" attribute?

Comment: It's 2019. To me order on date is not reliable, the order itself is fine but randomly there are video's not returned while they definitely exist. I have case where I list on a channelId. It has many video's of 10,11 and 12 september. One moment it does show them, few seconds later they're not returned by the api and the first ones are from 3rd september. Then moments later they are returned again. I checked it with the api test tool [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and it happens there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue all day, so after trying various parameters, I came here to look for information, and from what I can see, I'm not the only one.

It's as if the API sorts by relevance first and then by date, as it gives me 4 new videos initially, and the following 4 are mixed up.

Some videos have today's date, yesterday's, a week ago, a month ago, and so on. In between them, there are more videos.

I want to see the videos from my channel, sorted by date (it doesn't matter if it's upload date, publication date, or creation date). The same result that the YouTube website provides.

[https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=[CHANNEL](https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=%5BCHANNEL) ID]&maxResults=20&order=date&part=snippet&key=[KEY]
[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=[CHANNEL](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=%5BCHANNEL) ID]&maxResults=20&part=snippet&key=[KEY]
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?channelId=[CHANNEL](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?channelId=%5BCHANNEL) ID]&maxResults=20&part=snippet&key=[KEY]

Some show errors stating that there is no filter, the filter doesn't match, the chart filter doesn't match, etc

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: No, I couldn't, and according to what I've read, there's no way. It's something simple, but they haven't wanted to fix it. 

What I did was read all the videos, paginated by date ranges. 

After that, with a scheduled task that I run every X minutes, I only read the newest ones and compare to see if they already exist in my database. 

By reading them from my database, I can easily sort them by whatever I want.

Comment: Bummer. I opted for the RSS feed instead. Seems to be much easier in the sense that there's no rate limits, and it's always ordered correctly. Works if you just want to get videos for a single channel.